# Experience planning recreational activities a plus

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a paper ad:

> Assistant Cruise Director
>
> *Have you ever dreamed of seeing the world?* Here's your opportunity to get paid to do it!...You should love being around people from different cultures. Experience planning recreational activities a plus. Knowledge of languages desirable but not necessary.

What does 'a plus' mean here? I haven't seen this usage of plus before. Since this is an ad, I figured it might be ad language. Does it mean 'advantage' here because it's followed by 'Knowledge of languages' so that would be an advantage you'd have if knew some languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look for **plus** as a noun in the  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plus)  you will find that it means **an advantage or a good feature**, so your interpretation is correct. This isn't ad-speak: it is normal everyday language.

Note that there is probably a word missing: "Experience **of** planning recreational...".

Comment: Thanks. I doubted it because after _a plus_ there's a full stop, so  I wasn't sure why the phrase didn't appear after the full stop. And double-checked; there's no _of_ after experience. It might be a typo or it's a verb. I'm not sure.

Comment: Leaving out the "of" (or "with") is definitely common in help wanted ads. Originally it was because character count is sometimes a limitation, but it's almost a standard jargon at this point.

Comment: In AmE, "experience {doing something}" is ubiquitous.  **experience *in*** is also common, or **with**.